# How do I transfer the value of a label to another label that currently is in another form using visual basic?

Tags: c#

Increasing my score label 137 points per item I pickup

```
fMain

//HUD Score
        public int Score()
        {
            labScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
            labScore.Text = "00000" + score;

            if (score >= 10)
                labScore.Text = "0000" + score;
            if (score >= 100)
                labScore.Text = "000" + score;
            if (score >= 1000)
                labScore.Text = "00" + score;
            return score;

        }
```

And I want my labScore2.Text to be the same as labScore.text. But they are in different forms.

`fMain2`

```
public void btnIntroducir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fMain f = new fMain();
        f.Score();            
        try
        {
            string n = txtNombre.Text;
            int s = int32.Parse(labScore2.Text);
            lista[indice] = new Koby(n, s);
            indice++;
            muestraLista(ref lstJugadores);
            txtNombre.Clear();
            txtNombre.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: `new fMain();` You don't want a new instance; you want your existing instance.

Comment: I think you will get some hint [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062575/passing-values-between-forms-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is putting the value in a string that is not public. Either make the string public and access it from the other form or you can create a class and put all such variables in that class then access them from there when you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create a `Custom Event` for in `FMain2` that would reflect back to your `FMain` `LabScore.Text`.

In your `FMain2`, create the Custom Event. Let's say we create a `Custom Event` with  `score` as parameter. We will have the following:

```
public partial class FMain2 : Form
{
    public delegate void ScoreChangedEvent(String score); // Event Handler Delegate
    public event ScoreChangedEvent ScoreChanged; // Event Handler to subscribe to the Delegate

    public FMain2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In your `FMain` you could initialize the event and make the necessary changes when event is triggered, like:

```
    private void btnChangeScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormMain2 FMain2 = new FormMain2();
        FMain2.ScoreChanged += new FMain2.ScoreChangedEvent(FMain2_ScoreChanged);
        FMain2.Show();
    }
    void FMain2_ScoreChanged(string score)
    {
        labScore.Text = score; // This will receive the changes from FMain2 LabScore2.Text
    }
```

Then back in your `FMain2` you add the following:

```
public void btnIntroducir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string n = txtNombre.Text;
        int s = int32.Parse(labScore2.Text);
        ScoreChanged(labScore2.Text); // This will reflect back to FMain labScore.Text
        lista[indice] = new Koby(n, s);
        indice++;
        muestraLista(ref lstJugadores);
        txtNombre.Clear();
        txtNombre.Enabled = false;
    }
 }
```

So, your final code behind for your `FMain2` would be:

```
public partial class FMain2 : Form
{
    public delegate void ScoreChangedEvent(String score); // Event Handler Delegate
    public event ScoreChangedEvent ScoreChanged; // Event Handler to subscribe to the Delegate

    public FMain2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   public void btnIntroducir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     try
     {
        string n = txtNombre.Text;
        int s = int32.Parse(labScore2.Text);
        ScoreChanged(labScore2.Text); // This will reflect back to FMain labScore.Text
        lista[indice] = new Koby(n, s);
        indice++;
        muestraLista(ref lstJugadores);
        txtNombre.Clear();
        txtNombre.Enabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```