# I have to use a serial port that is shared across two UIs in C# .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I have a C# application that opens up two GUIs at startup.
One of the GUI opens three virtual COM Ports. I want the other GUI that is a part of the same application to show the data that is being sent on those virtual COM Ports. Is there anyway to share this COM Port declaration that I do in the Main/First GUI that I am opening up.

Comment: You can pass references to them in the `ctor` of the window that does not create them. I don't remember if 2 windows use the same UI thread or not, but you may need to `Invoke()` actions on them if they don't share a common thread.

Comment: @PeteGarafano For each process there's only one UI thread, at least in .net

Comment: Does your first sentence mean you have one WinForm app that has to share data between two forms? Consult [Passing data between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062575/).

Comment: Thanks @Gusman, that should simplify this to just passing the objects to the one window once they are constructed by the first window.

Answer (score 1):

**Three ways:**

**1) Copy the instance of the connection from Window1 to Window2.**

`window2.Connection = this.Connection;`

**2) Make it the connection a public static member**

```
class Window1 : Window
{
   public static SerialConnectionClass Connection { get; set; } = new SerialConnectionClass();
}
```

You can access the connection like that:

```
class Window2 :Window
{
...
   private void func()
   {
      Window1.Connection.Send("");
   }
}
```

**3) Make a static ConnectionManager**

```
static class ConnectionManager
{
    public static SerialConnectionClass Connection { get; set; } = new SerialConnectionClass();
    public static EventHandler MessageReceived;
    public static void Send(string text)
    {
        Connection.Send(text);
    }
    ...
}
```

Use it in Window1 and Window2 like this:

```
class Window2 :Window
{
...
   private void func()
   {
      ConnectionManager.init("COM1");
      ConnectionManager.MessageReceived += this.MessageReceived;
      ConnectionManager.Send("test123");
   }
}
```