# Passing Textbox Values one form to another form in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to get an input values from user for drawing a Circle ( for this I use Radius input) and a Rectangle ( Edge1 and Edge2 ) inputs. I want to pass these textboxt values on another form to draw them.
How can I move these values to another form in properties section or any solution ideas?

Forms are in the same project by the way.

I defined an interface and implement processes about calculations. My code is below and worked, thank you for responds.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment2
{
    class CircleShape : Shape, IShape
    {
        public int radius;
        public CircleShape(int radius)
        {
            this.radius = radius;


        }
        public double CalculateArea()
        {
            return Math.PI * radius * radius;
        }

        public double CalculatePerimeter()
        {
            return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one of the most commonly asked questions here. There are tons of answers available already. Just search the site and you'll find them.

Comment: Be more specific.  Give names to the forms and tell us which one does the drawing, and which one has the inputs.  Also tell us which form creates the other one.  Does the info need to be in real-time?...or does the drawing only happen after dismissing the input form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing values between forms (winforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062575/passing-values-between-forms-winforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just have a method on your second form that returns any needed details

```
using (DrawForm drawForm = new DrawForm ())
{
    drawForm.ShowDialog(); //will wait for the form to close before continuing
    var userResults = drawForm.GetResults(); //returns whatever you need the form to return
    return userResults;
}
```

The above logic only works if the second form is a popup form of sorts. If you want both forms to be persistent, then it's a bit different. You might want to ensure both forms have access to each other. When you create the drawform be sure to save a reference to it. and in the constructor for your drawform add an argument to include the main form.

```
  DrawForm drawForm = new DrawForm(this);//now the forms can talk to each other
```

in your drawing form when the user hits 'go'

```
 mainForm.TriggerFinishedDrawing(drawingObject);
```

There are several ways to achieve this sort of behaviour, you just need to decide what sort of flow makes the most sense in your use case

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to pass data from a form to another one is that you can use [`Application.OpenForms Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=net-5.0).

First, define a `TextBox property` to access the TextBox instance in Form1.

```
// Form1.cs
public TextBox TB
{
    get { return textBox1; }
    set { textBox1 = value; }
}
```

Then call `Application.OpenForms` to get Form1 instance.

```
// Form2.cs
Form1 fr = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
if (fr != null)
{
    Form1 f1 = (Form1)fr;
    // get text form Form1.textbox1
    MessageBox.Show(f1.TB.Text);
}
```

---

If Form2 is opened by clicking the button in Form1 and pass the value when Form2 shown, you can achieve it via `constructor`.

```
// Form1.cs
private void btnOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
    f2.Show();
}

// From2.cs
string textformForm1;
public Form2(string str)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textformForm1 = str;
}

private void btnShowText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(textformForm1);
}
```

Similarly, you can also use public properties.

```
// Form1.cs
private void btnOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.TextformForm1 = textBox1.Text;
    f2.Show();
}

// Form2.cs
public string TextformForm1 { get; set; }

private void btnShowText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(TextformForm1);
}
```