# Passing a variable between forms WINFORMS

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C# and Winforms.

I have been trying to pass the username variable from form 1 to be used in form 3 and it is not working. I have been searching forever for a solution and I am confused as to why it is not working. In the label, nothing is showing up except for the string.
Any help is appreciated!

FORM 1:

```
public static string username;

private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (successfulLogin == true)
            {

                username = tb_username.Text;
                Form3 form = new Form3();
                form.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Log in unsuccessful. Please make sure your credentials are correct or sign up");
                tb_password.Clear();
                tb_username.Clear();
                tb_username.Select();
            }
}
```

FORM3:

```
public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            usernameChange();
        }

private void usernameChange()
        {
            label1.Text = Form1.username + ", please create, review or manage your flashcards below";
        }
```

Comment: "and it is not working" Why is it not working? Is something else displayed as expected? Do you get an exception or a compiling error?

Comment: Sorry, I realised this after I posted it. Nothing shows up in the label except for the string @SomeBody

Comment: @jdweng: It seems that you have posted the wrong link...

Comment: @EthanH Are you sure that `tb_username.Text` is not an empty string? Because the code you showed us looks fine.

Comment: @SomeBody It shouldn't be because it is used for login and works fine.

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form. See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net?force_isolation=true

Comment: Do you by any chance clear the textbox text after you login successfully?

Comment: static references for these reasons aren't the best way to go. Better change your Form3 constructor to Form3(string username) and pass the username this way when you instantiate the form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing values between forms (winforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062575/passing-values-between-forms-winforms) and [Passing variable between winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247807/passing-variable-between-winforms) and [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)